# Warnings shows up in message window

Tags: options, message-coding

I have no idea why, but suddenly all my evaluation with warnings (like `Sum::div:Sum does not converge`) has begun to show up in a message box. Since always they appeared between `In[]` and `Out[]`?

How do I make it act normally again?

Answer (score 10):

You can control how Messages are sent under Edit->Preferences. Choose the Messages tab and select your prefered behavior.

[image]

Comment: This seems not to work in Mma V11.
Christoph Haenel

Comment: This does not appear to be the case in v12 either