# Warning message in current window in v12

Tags: warning-messages

I don't remember exactly when, but warning messages started to show up in a new window.
I found a post about this

[Warnings shows up in message window](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25986/warnings-shows-up-in-message-window)

The poster gives us solution - change an option in the preference.
But such option (Messages tab) doesn't exist in mathematica **version 12**.

How can I show warning messages between In[] and Out[] in mathematica **version 12**?